Why does SSRS advanced grouping display differently depending on how a table group is set up?
Consider the two scenarios when creating a table with a row group, imagine the data is simply personID, surname, forename, gender.
Scenario 1
Table in this case can look like below in SSRS.


Insert new table and set up the three columns to have Surname, Forename, Gender.
Edit the default "Details" row group to whatever we wish to group by our dataset, say "personID".
Enable "Advanced" mode on the group pane and you should have the below group structure.


I understand this structure, our table has two rows and three column hence two row groups and three column groups. However this is not the case in the second scenario.
Scenario 2

Insert new table and again set the same three columns, Surname, Forename, Gender.
Now instead lets delete the existing "Details" group (making sure to delete the group only), let's pretend we created a table with no intention to have a row group, but later change our mind.
Now lets add a new parent row group on the second row of the table. Right click the first cell in the second row and select Add Group > Row Group > Parent Group. Lets group by whatever we can in our dataset.
Now the table creates a new column for the field which we use to group by, but it also adds these dashed lines I suppose to represent this as the row group area? Lets delete this new column to try and achieve the same table as in Scenario 1 choose "Delete columns only" to preserve the row group.
Now our table looks like the first one.


But what confuses me is this new weird group layout when we now view the advanced group pane at the bottom.

How can there be three row groups when the table only has two rows? Does it have any impact on the way the data will be laid out in this case? How could I achieve the more clear advanced group layout like in the first scenario?
I cannot seem to get the same group structure unless I basically create a new table from scratch, which seems odd.
I tried to use the table from the second scenario to recreate the group pane structure as in the first scenario. I tried to completely delete the row group and add a new one, but the row group structure always has an additional static row in the group pane, only way around it is to completely recreate the table and never to delete the original details row group. I also read through the Microsoft pages on the SSRS tables and groupings here, but did not find a suitable explanation.

How did you delete the "Details" group? Did you delete the detail row under the header or use the grouping pane?
